# Set variable to SCOPE_IDENTITY inside of IF statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, if-statement

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will check for the existence of a record and if it does not exist do an insert returning the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and if it does exist simply return the ID of the object. After I get this information in the procedure I need to do further processing with it and am unsure of how to accomplish getting the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` from within an `IF...ELSE` statement.

My two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActionTable] (
    [ActionID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActionName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectTable] (
    [ObjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
)
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetAction]
    @ActionName [nvarchar](255),
    @ObjectName [nvarchar](255)
AS
    DECLARE @ObjectID [int]

    --I have tried the following

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ObjectID FROM ObjectTable WHERE ObjectName = @ObjectName)
        INSERT INTO ObjectTable(ObjectName)VALUES(@ObjectName)
        --Here I need to set @ObjectID = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    ELSE
        SELECT @ObjectID = ObjectID FROM ObjectTable WHERE ObjectName = @ObjectName
```

This returns `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'`

What would be the best method for accomplishing this lookup/insert? After I get the ID I will then do the following

```
INSERT INTO ActionTable(ObjectID, ActionName) VALUES(@ObjectID, @ActionName)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have more than one thing to do you need a BEGIN END

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ObjectID FROM ObjectTable WHERE ObjectName = @ObjectName)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ObjectTable(ObjectName)VALUES(@ObjectName)
    SET @ObjectID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @ObjectID = ObjectID FROM ObjectTable WHERE ObjectName = @ObjectName
END
```

Answer (score 4):

You should always use BEGIN / END even for only one statement so that when you add statements later your code doesn't break.

```
IF ...
BEGIN
    ... statements
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    ... statements
END
```